# How do I run an Azure Functions App on Premise?

Tags: .net-core, console-application, azure-function-app, .net-core-2.1

I currently have a .NET Core 2.1 Azure Functions app with a timer trigger.  Due to a change in network landscape, the functions app in Azure no longer has network access to the database resources it needs.  We've thought about repointing the application to a webservice instead of the database, but need a lift-and-shift solution in the short term, and we have an on-premise server that is set up to run batch job console apps.

**Is there any easy way to run an Azure Functions app via the command line?**  It seems to work that way from the Visual Studio debugger.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools) to run Azure Functions via the command line.

After following the instructions at the link above to install the tools navigate to the project root directory (containing the `local.settings.json` file) and do a `func start` to run the Azure functions runtime host.